# How to host MVC application in sitecore which is installed in virtual machine

Tags: azure, sitecore, virtual-machine, sitecore-mvc, sitecore7.5

We have sitecore 7.5 which is installed in virtual machine in azure environment.
How to publish my local visual studio application to sitecore which is in the virtual machine?.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use a build server.

And use somethings as https://github.com/JorritSalverda/msbuild-by-convention

For Azure deploy, we do first a delete of the previous release (don't delete Sitecore). (we do not have Sitecore in version control, or as a NuGet package) and after that a Azure deploy.

For just a simple development purpose in your Azure VM Visual studio you can create a publish profile. (on the same VM, you can use a file system deploy)